# Load same webView instance on all tabbars in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, wkwebview

I wanted to know if it is possible to load same **WKWebView** instance in all the tabbars in **UITabBarViewController**. If it is yes then please share some thoughts/ideas.

I wanted to achieve this thing:-

**Tabbar1:-** load stackOverflow.com > tap anywhere> it will load another URL

**Tabbar 2:-** Want to see the new loaded URL here (from the first tab)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Feel like a bad idea to show same thing in different tab!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to shared the same instance, but you must know:

> A view cannot be added to two different views at the same time. Each
> view in UIKit hierarchy can have only one superview at a time. If you
> add a view to a second superview, it will be removed from its previous
> superview.

So, the trick here is putting the wkwebview in a shared AppDelegate, and inside your individual childViewController add the shared wkwebview as a child view within `viewWillAppear(_ animated:)`

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    debugPrint("\(#function)")
    sharedWebView.frame = view.bounds
    sharedWebView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(sharedWebView)
  }
```

In this way, you have have a shared wkwebview.

[image]

BTW, I have trouble understanding you request, but still, I wrote a demo project:

> Tabbar1:- load stackOverflow.com > tap anywhere> it will load another
> URL
>
> Tabbar 2:- Want to see the new loaded URL here (from the first tab)

[Check the whole project here](https://github.com/kasimok/76313176)